# How to ask for a bigger salary when you have a few job offers?

Tags: job-offer, new-job

I have 3 job offers and they all offer almost the same salary. All companies are where I'd like to work so the final deciding factor would be salary. How could I nicely tell them that I have 2 other job offers and I'd like an increase in the salary in their offer? Thank you.

Comment: How about asking? It is a negotiation process, play the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I was looking for my first job, 4 companies need me. I just said them : "Well, I will think about your offer, I just warn you I have 2 more offers." And one them offer me the top range I was asking.
Don't forget that if you need job, they also need a worker. I don't know your kind of job (IT, marketing, ...) but if this is frequently asked job offers, you have the power.
Don't be to ambicious, but just tell them they have contestant.